# undefined method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined

I get the error

```
undefined method `favorite_relationships_path'
```

when I display this form:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.favorite_relationships.build(lesson_id: @lesson.id),
             remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :lesson_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Favorite", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure why. I have a controller called favorite_relationships_controller.rb and a model file, favorite_relationship.rb, with the code

```
class FavoriteRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :lesson_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :lesson
end
```

My user model also has:

```
  has_many :favorite_relationships
  has_many :lessons, :through => :favorite_relationships
```

I'm really not sure why im getting that error. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining controllers, actions and views is not enough. You need to define *routes* in `config/routes.rb` to connect URLs to your controllers/actions. Defining RESTful resources with `resources :favourite_relationships` in your routing file is what causes Rails to generate the `*_path` and `*_url` helpers; until you do this there is no way for requests to reach your app, and no way for your app to generate routes based on your models.

Your routes file should look something like this:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :favourite_relationships
end
```

This generates the typical "CRUD" routes required for a RESTful resource:

```
favourite_relationships     GET    /favourite_relationships(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"favourite_relationships"}
                            POST   /favourite_relationships(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"favourite_relationships"}
 new_favourite_relationship GET    /favourite_relationships/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"favourite_relationships"}
edit_favourite_relationship GET    /favourite_relationships/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"favourite_relationships"}
     favourite_relationship GET    /favourite_relationships/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"favourite_relationships"}
                            PUT    /favourite_relationships/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"favourite_relationships"}
                            DELETE /favourite_relationships/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"favourite_relationships"}
```

Comment: Ah, we wrote almost-identical answers at the same time! :)

Comment: oh dang, i totally forgot about that. i was only thinking about the url in my routes file, ie like having it under something like localhost:3000/lessons/favorites. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Rails has `_path` and `_url` helpers for routes, which are set up in `config/routes.rb`. You'll need to ensure that you've defined the routes for `FavouriteRelationshipController`; something like:

```
resources :favourite_relationships
```

You can check the routes defined for your application using the `rake routes` command.

You can find more information about routing at the [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) guide.

Comment: oh dang, i totally forgot about that. i was only thinking about the url in my routes file, ie like having it under something like localhost:3000/lessons/favorites. thanks a lot!